# Access current logged-in user from anywhere in the code

Tags: django

Is there any function or global object by which I can access current logged-in user from anywhere in the Django project? If not, what will be the workaround?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is covered in either part 1 or 2 of the tutorial.

Comment: @Sayse It is absolutely clear how to access user object from within the views or templates. But I have separate utils.py file with supporting functions,   where some of them require access to user object. If you still think I miss that from tutorial, please show

Answer (score 1):

Found [this solution](https://blndxp.wordpress.com/2016/03/04/django-get-current-user-anywhere-in-your-code-using-a-middleware/) . After that, you have to add your new custom middleware class to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in the settings

Comment: It is, of course, possible to hack around and expose request as a global. The problem with this approach is that user is request specific by nature. If you start using a user in mode code, for example, your model code will fail to load in any context that doesn't have a user (like django console)

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. Django is all about requests and responses. User is specific to a particular request. When you have a request, you can access the user as request.user. Otherwise, no, you cannot.

Comment: thank you. Found that one of the solution will be to write custom middleware class as demonstrated [here](https://blndxp.wordpress.com/2016/03/04/django-get-current-user-anywhere-in-your-code-using-a-middleware/). Works for me

Comment: see my comment on the answer that suggests custom middleware, there is a good reason user is not a global object, since some parts of the code should work even out of web context

Answer (score 0):

Try this
middleware.py

```
try:
    from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
except ImportError:
    MiddlewareMixin = object
import threading

class CRequestMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    """
    Provides storage for the "current" request object, so that code anywhere
    in your project can access it, without it having to be passed to that code
    from the view.
    """
    _requests = {}

    def process_request(self, request):
        """
        Store the current request.
        """
        self.__class__.set_request(request)

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        """
        Delete the current request to avoid leaking memory.
        """
        self.__class__.del_request()
        return response

    @classmethod
    def get_request(cls, default=None):
        """
        Retrieve the request object for the current thread, or the optionally
        provided default if there is no current request.
        """
        return cls._requests.get(threading.current_thread(), default)

    @classmethod
    def set_request(cls, request):
        """
        Save the given request into storage for the current thread.
        """
        cls._requests[threading.current_thread()] = request

    @classmethod
    def del_request(cls):
        """
        Delete the request that was stored for the current thread.
        """
        cls._requests.pop(threading.current_thread(), None)
```

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    '<path>.CRequestMiddleware',
]
```

anywhere.py

```
def global_request():
    from utilities.middlewares import CRequestMiddleware
    return CRequestMiddleware.get_request()

def current_user():
    return global_request().user
current_user()
```

Answer (score -4):

On templates

```
{{ user }}
```

on views.py

```
request.user
```

Comment: In no way is this an answer to OP's question at all.